# How to count the length of strings stored inside a pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm looking at [wine review data from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/zynicide/wine-reviews), and trying to practice using pandas. I'm running into a bit of an issue. What I'd like to do is group the wines into their country and variety, and then determine the average length of a description that wine reviewers have given a particular variety of wine from a particular country.

To do this, I've attempted

`average_desc = reviews.groupby(['country','variety']).description.apply(lambda x: len(x)).mean()`

but all this gives me is some mean value. I don't quite know what the issue is, or how I could provide more information, first post here so let me know how to clarify. I thought that once

`reviews.groupby(['country','variety']).description`

I'm essentially looking at the column which contains the wine descriptions sorted by variety, and just need to convert to the length of the strings inside the columns then take the mean. One thing I can say is that

`average_desc = reviews.groupby(['country','variety']).description.apply(lambda x: len(x))`

returns a count of how many of the different varieties of wines are to be found in the country below

```
country    variety                   
Argentina  Barbera                         1
           Bonarda                       105
           Bordeaux-style Red Blend       89
           Bordeaux-style White Blend      1
           Cabernet Blend                  8
                                        ... 
Uruguay    Tannat-Cabernet Franc           2
           Tannat-Merlot                   6
           Tannat-Syrah                    1
           Tempranillo-Tannat              1
           White Blend                     1
Name: description, Length: 1612, dtype: int64
```

So is there an issue of not indexing *far enough* into the dataframe? Thanks in advance for the help, and let me know if I need to write more to clarify the situation.

Comment: Scott has the answer already, but to give you an explanation, you need to find out the lengths of the descriptions before doing the groupby. The way you have it, you're grouping first and so description becomes a series. You're getting the length(which is now the count) of the series instead of the individual descriptions.

Comment: Thanks @MC10! I was wondering why my implementation wasn't doing it, I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I think you want something like this:

```
reviews['description'].str.len().groupby([df['country'], df['variety']]).mean()
```

Output:

```
country    variety                   
Argentina  Barbera                       236.000000
           Bonarda                       242.123810
           Bordeaux-style Red Blend      311.426966
           Bordeaux-style White Blend    274.000000
           Cabernet Blend                281.000000
                                            ...    
Uruguay    Tannat-Cabernet Franc         300.500000
           Tannat-Merlot                 258.333333
           Tannat-Syrah                  275.000000
           Tempranillo-Tannat            260.000000
           White Blend                   248.000000
Name: description, Length: 1612, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why is it that by using `groupby([df['country'], df['variety']])` as you have, that the computer knows how to group the data even after we've restricted to a series with `reviews.description.str.len()`? Because isn't that just a series and not the full data frame? Does the associated information from the dataframe still get associated to the values as a standard pandas feature?

Comment: Good question...  What is in the groupby just needs to be a list of values equal to the lenght of  the dataframe.  That list can be any groupings you desire.   We choose a list containing two series from the dataframe in the same order, therefore it creates a grouping of the .str.len results based on theses values.

Comment: You could have put in groupby ['A']*len(df)//2+['B']*(len(df)-len(df)//2). To group the values by first half and send half labeling the groups A and B.

Comment: Succinct and illuminating clarification, thank you.